# How to Join 2 Tables in SQL Server on a Field having ForeName and Surnames in unknown order

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, join

Wondering if you could help me with something. We get agency invoices for workers who worked for different clients on our behalf. Now these Invoices have worker's surname and Forenames in completely random order. Now my SSIS package import these invoices to a database. I am trying to automate few reports based on this data. Now i would like to Join this Invoice data with our data warehouse Employee and Shift table. Only fields i can join this on is Name and Shift date. How can i Join the DW Employee table to Imported Invoices as Names in Invoice tables are all over the place. Any nice SQL function that can help ,e. I have tried Joins using Concat and Like but it didn't work. Suggestions would be highly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Thanks and Regards

Khurram

Comment: Provide some sample data please

Comment: @gulshanarora Hi Mate, Table contents shared.

Comment: Totally out of left field here, but I don't know sql server all that well. (asking the experts here) would it be possible to build a UDF that takes two arguments (name from one table and name from the other) and returns a bool for the ON condition like `ON MyNameMatchFunction(table1.name, table2.name)`? I feel like one could get pretty creative in a UDF where one might be limited writing this out in the sql.

Comment: why not fix the design of your db and make 2 columns for the name in stead of one

Answer (score 2):

This is a real challenge for you. Others have already suggested that you might not want to do this, but I will give it a shot anyway. I think you need to create two parts, the first part and the second part, in both tables. Then you can compare them. The following code might lead you in the right direction:

```
SELECT LEFT ('John Jackson', CHARINDEX (' ', 'John Jackson')  - 1) AS FirstPart,
       SUBSTRING ('John Jackson', CHARINDEX (' ', 'John Jackson'), LEN ('John Jackson') - CHARINDEX (' ', 'John Jackson') + 1) AS SecondPart

SELECT * 
FROM TableA AS A 
    LEFT JOIN TableB AS B ON A.FirstPart = B.FirstPart AND A.SecondPart = B.SecondPart

   UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB AS B2 ON  A.FirstPart = B2.SecondPart AND A.SecondPart = B2.FirstPart
```

Good luck in handling this!

Comment: Thanks very much mate, will definitely give it a try

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, this is a challenge with no good answer outside of a redesign. But, like SQL_M, I figured I'd try it. Assuming that dwEmployee is the source of record, I initially went with something similar to SQL_M's approach with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.invoiceTable i
JOIN dwEmployee d
ON 
    (
        d.[DW_personname] LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING(i.[Name],0,CHARINDEX(' ',i.[name])),' %')
        OR d.[DW_personname] LIKE CONCAT('% ',SUBSTRING(i.[Name],0,CHARINDEX(' ',i.[name])),'%')
    )
AND 
(
    d.[DW_personname] LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING(i.[Name],CHARINDEX(' ',i.[name])+1,LEN(I.[Name]) - CHARINDEX(' ',i.[name])),' %')
    OR d.[DW_personname] LIKE CONCAT('% ',SUBSTRING(i.[Name],CHARINDEX(' ',i.[name])+1,LEN(I.[Name]) - CHARINDEX(' ',i.[name])),'%')
)
```

It works great until it hits a name that has three distinct parts... and then I couldn't be buggered to get it working - I'm leaving it here in case it helps you build on something.

I ended up using a CTE and STRING_SPLIT combination to make potential matches across the tables. You had mentioned that you can join on Shiftdate, but didn't say exactly how you wanted the results to look, and it seemed the name join was the big issue, so I just focused on that. Depending on what version of SQL you're on STRING_SPLIT might not be available to you, in which case you'd have to use a different split function to make this method work. (demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4bd31/2/1 )

```
CREATE TABLE invoiceTable
(
    [Invoice_ID] INT, [ShiftDate] DATE, [Ref_Num] INT, [Name] VARCHAR(200)
)

CREATE TABLE dwEmployee
(
    [Shiftdate] DATE, [DW_personname] VARCHAR(200), [Timesheetserial] VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.invoiceTable
VALUES
(807, '2018-09-02',83789315,'ABCD EFGH'), (195, '2018-09-14',83789315,'EFGH ABCD'), (227, '2018-09-15',83789315,'WXYZ EFGH-ABCD'), (246, '2018-09-16',83789315,'JKLM OPQR'),(1398, '2018-09-19',83789315,'STUV IJKKL WXYZ')

INSERT INTO dbo.dwEmployee
VALUES
( '2018-10-22','EFGH ABCD','Z3746543'), ( '2018-10-29','EFIH ABCD','Z3746550'), ( '2018-10-26','EFGH-ABCD WXYZ','Z3746557'),( '2018-10-26','EFGH-ABCD WXYZ','Z3746557')

--my additional insert for testing three-part name

INSERT INTO dbo.dwEmployee
VALUES
( '2018-10-31','WXYZ STUV IJKKL','Z0000000');

--work
WITH nameSplitter AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Invoice_ID], CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(200)) AS [Timesheetserial], [Value]
    FROM invoiceTable
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([Name], ' ')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        NULL, [Timesheetserial], Value
    FROM dwEmployee
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([DW_personname], ' ')
),
potentialMatches AS
(
    SELECT 
        ns1.[Invoice_ID], ns2.[Timesheetserial]
    FROM nameSplitter ns1
    JOIN nameSplitter ns2
        ON ns2.value = ns1.value
    WHERE ns1.[Invoice_ID] IS NOT NULL
        AND ns2.[Timesheetserial] IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ns1.[Invoice_ID], ns2.[Timesheetserial]
    HAVING COUNT(ns2.[Timesheetserial]) = (SELECT COUNT([Timesheetserial]) FROM nameSplitter WHERE [Timesheetserial] = ns2.[Timesheetserial] )
)
SELECT i.*, d.* 
FROM potentialMatches p
join dbo.invoiceTable i
    ON P.[Invoice_ID] = I.[Invoice_ID]
JOIN dwEmployee d
    ON p.[Timesheetserial] = d.[Timesheetserial]
```

Comment: Many thanks Buddy, i will definitely give it a try. I was already using Like and Concat and match rate was 50%. Will it a shot. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you only got one forename and one surname, you could try something like this:

```
....
FROM tableA AS A
INNER JOIN tableB AS B
    ON A.Name = B.DW_personname OR A.Name = RIGHT(B.DW_personname, LEN(DW_personname) - CHARINDEX(' ', B.DW_personname) +1) + ' ' + LEFT(B.DW_personname, CHARINDEX(' ', B.DW_personname))
```